# How to setup Client VPN Endpoint to use AWS DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, vpn, internal-dns, amazon-route53

I'm trying to allow VPN users to use Private Route53 DNS entries.  Eg: a private hosted zone `example.corp` issuing DNS records on the local network.

At the moment I can't even find the right set of configurations to allow connected clients to use amazon's DNS at all.

### Current (simplified) setup

The client VPN endpoint is allocated CIDR range `172.20.0.0/22`.  It has one configured target network association which has CIDR `172.20.254.0/24`.

The target network is empty; meaning no EC2 instances live there etc..  However it does itself have onward routing rules to allow traffic to other networks.  Access to those onward routes is controlled through "Authorization Rules".  The route table has just one entry stating `172.20.0.0/16` (the whole VPC) is forwarded to the target network association.

The security group associated with the VPN is very permissive allowing anything on `172.20.0.0/16`.

This configuration has worked without DNS for over a year. The only changes I'm now making are to enable DNS.

### Changes - Attempting to enable DNS

[This page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/client-vpn-resolve-resource-records/) tells me that the DNS should be available on the network range +2.  I've tried setting the VPN DNS server to `172.20.0.2` and `172.20.254.0` *(not at the same time)*.  But neither respond to DNS request or ICMP ping.

In an attempt to get this working I have tried:

- Ensured that "DNS resolution" and "DNS hostnames" were both set on the VPC
- Adding Authorization Rules for both `172.20.254.0/24` and `172.20.0.2/22`.
- Adding route table entry for `172.20.0.0/22` to `local`

**How am I supposed to setup Client VPN Endpoint to use AWS DNS?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VPN's own CIDR block is not supposed to be part of your VPC's CIDR block and exists outside the VPC.

As above my associated subnet was on `172.20.254.0/24`, part of VPC CIDR `172.20.0.0/16`.  Having the VPN's CIDR block be `172.20.0.0/22` was problematic because it overlapped the all important `172.20.0.2` which is the DNS IP on the VPC.

One real point of confusion here is that the DNS IP does not need to be in any subnet at all.

### Solution

- I tore down the VPN and moved it's CIDR to `172.16.0.0/22` so that it no-longer overlapped the VPC's CIDR `172.20.0.0/16`.
- I made sure there was an Authorization Rule allowing traffic to the DNS IP `172.20.0.2`: IE `172.20.0.2/32`.
- I did not **need** any subnet overlapping the DNS IP
- It did still work after I moved the "empty" subnet to overlap the DNS IP.